# Google Analytics phone call tracking, where to put code

Tags: bootstrap-4, google-analytics, ads, event-tracking

I have been supplied some code to put into a website to track Google ads which result in a phone call, the first part of the code goes between the head tags, however not sure where to put this part (the marketing company said to put where number appears in the body but I'm not sure)

```html
<script>

  gtag('config', 'AW-819601053/HpfiCIHgu-cCEJ296IYD', {

    'phone_conversion_number': '0800 368 9125'

  });

</script>
```

I have searched but no clear guidance could be found.

Comment: Did you run into a problem when placing it in the body where the number appears?  Does it not work there?

Comment: I havent as yet but it didnt sound correct to put in the body, nit sure to put it before the number or after

Comment: I'd try using their suggestion and see if it works. They should know how to use their snippet.  JavaScript will run from the body.

Comment: Thanks, ive inserted it and will see